# HP D2D 4312 Bacula configuration

Tags: linux, hp, bacula, deduplication

I have configured 5 libraries on the HP D2D system

[image: Thumbnail link to screenshot of HP D2D]

Discovery on the Bacula server shows only the last library and not all libraries. Why?

```
[root@server bacula]# iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal 10.66.59.114
10.66.59.114:3260,1 iqn.1986-03.com.hp:storage.d2dbs.czj2020vvy.50014380075dca5e.library12.drive1
10.66.59.114:3260,1 iqn.1986-03.com.hp:storage.d2dbs.czj2020vvy.50014380075dcaf2.library12.robotics
```

I can query it fine using...

```
[root@server bacula]# mtx -f /dev/sg2 inquiry
Product Type: Tape Drive
Vendor ID: 'HP      '
Product ID: 'Ultrium 5-SCSI  '
Revision: 'ED51'
Attached Changer API: No
[root@bray bacula]# mtx -f /dev/sg3 inquiry
Product Type: Medium Changer
Vendor ID: 'HP      '
Product ID: 'MSL G3 Series   '
Revision: 'EL41'
Attached Changer API: No


[root@server bacula]# mtx -f /dev/sg3 status
  Storage Changer /dev/sg3:1 Drives, 97 Slots ( 1 Import/Export )
Data Transfer Element 0:Empty
      Storage Element 1:Full :VolumeTag=50507F82                            
      Storage Element 2:Full :VolumeTag=50507F83                            
      Storage Element 3:Full :VolumeTag=50507F84                            
      Storage Element 4:Full :VolumeTag=50507F85                            
      Storage Element 5:Full :VolumeTag=50507F86                            
      Storage Element 6:Full :VolumeTag=50507F87                            
      Storage Element 7:Full :VolumeTag=50507F88
```

Does anyone have any good documentation for implementing Bacula with an HP D2D tape drive for server backups, and how to allocate libraries?